# generated html shows php symbol instead of value

Tags: php, html, audio, symbols

I want to be able to play all of the audio files in my database via by embedding the source in a player.

I have created an sql query that will return an array containing all of my mp3 names.

I then use a while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$sourcefile=$row['location'];
echo '<audio controls>';
echo '<source src="$sourcefile" type="audio/mpeg">';
echo "$sourcefile";
echo '</audio>';
}
```

Which results in the following html:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="$sourcefile" type"audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

If I explicitly substitute the $sourcefile, within the audio tag, with songname.mp3 it works just fine.

And just to make sure the php variable is getting the correct value, I used an echo statement to see the value it contained and it is indeed songname.mp3.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable substitution only happens inside double-quoted strings, not single-quoted strings. Change it:

```
echo "<source src='$sourcefile' type='audio/mpeg'>";
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you immeasurably.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
echo "<source src='{$sourcefile}' type='audio/mpeg'>";
```

Or this:

```
<source src="<?php echo $sourcefile; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
```

**Remember** (HTML & PHP) don't mix without their tags :)

Comment: The `"` after `src=` ends the string, so that won't work. And you're missing `=` after `type`.

Comment: Thanx about `=` after `type`.
But about the `"` after `src=` it works , because I used **`{}`** not `.$sorcefile.` , try it by yourself.

Comment: I suggest you try it, you should get a syntax error.

Comment: I just tried it, I got `Parse error: parse error, expecting \`','' or \`';'' `

Comment: Now it works, it's the same as my answer. You don't need the `{}` since it's a simple variable.